# provide samples of creating flowcharts for scripts

Tags: flowchart

My 17 year old is sitting for his national N Level Computer applications paper soon. He's really weak in creating flow charts from scripts and need him to practise everyday till the start of his paper- is it possible to get samples or can you help create such questions for him to try? These are the type of questions from past papers in the link: https://acrobat.adobe.com/id/urn:aaid:sc:AP:86a74294-89cf-40a6-b35b-ce8c94e47fdc

He gets stuck trying to set up the flow chart

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I wanted to suggest a fantastic book on this, but I can't recall the title. Regardless, googling along the lines of "flowchart book" might help.